# Get Azure directory role of the user using B2C graph API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I want to read which directory roles are assigned to Azure AD users (like Global Administrator). I tried the following API but it is not returning anything.

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

Is there any API to which we can pass UPN and get the list of roles under that user?

Comment: Please check this to List Azure AD role assignments for a user https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/roles/list-role-assignments-users.md

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@JayakrishnaGunnam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969077/jayakrishnagunnam-mt) for your suggestion.

To get roles assigned to a user directly, use the [List roleAssignments](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments) API. Select **Run query** after adding the following query to the URL.

```
GET     https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/rolemanagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=principalId eq '55c07278-7109-4a46-ae60-4b644bc83a31'
```

**REFERENCES:**
[List role assignments users](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/roles/list-role-assignments-users.md)